# JRuby running multiple instances of a program

Tags: ruby, multithreading, jruby, fork

I'm trying to write a load test that emulates the creation of thousands of ActiveRecord objects at around the same time.

So the basic idea is to get ids of thousands of different ActiveRecord objects and for each object create another object that belongs to it.

Forking doesn't work well on JRuby so I can't use forks.

I'm thinking of using bash scripts that run the same ruby script with different parameters passed into it.

Is there a better way to do this?

a little sudo code:

```
for ids in [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,6...] |id|
  MyMode.find(1).create_some_other_model(1) // happen in the background
end
```

So pretty much I don't want the line that is supposed to happen on the background on a separate process make the whole program wait every time.

Comment: Try adding code examples to clarify your question.

Comment: I put some sudo code, hope it helps

Comment: Why can't you just start threads? Especially with jruby_threach?

Comment: so the call  it's gonna be a tcp call, and too many threads in tcp get shut down.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using JRuby, you can use threads (a JRuby thread is a Java thread, which in turns maps to a native thread); see [this post](http://ybits.net/2012/03/the-case-for-jruby-part-1-threading/) for an example, and also have a look at the [JRuby wiki](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Concurrency-in-jruby).

Comment: My Calls are going to be TCP separate calls so I can't have that many threads.